# removeClass works instantly, addClass only works on lose focus

Tags: jquery, css

I have buttons which allow users to toggle the visibility of elements on the page. When an element is visible, the button should be highlighted.

When it becomes invisible, the highlighting vanishes instantly, as desired. But when it becomes visible, the highlighting only appears when the button loses focus.

```
if (column.visible()) {            
    $(button).addClass("highlight");
}
else {
    $(button).removeClass("highlight");
}
```

In other words, "remove CSS class" has an instant effect, but "add CSS class" does not. What might be going on here?

Update:
Here's JSFiddle showing this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/f7cwfr3x/7/

Comment: What event are you running your code under? Also note that you can make it a one-liner: `$(button).toggleClass("highlight", column.visible());`

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's running on click: $('button.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) ...
Thanks for the shorter version; unfortunately the problem still persists with that version.

Comment: can you post some html ?

Comment: it seems toggle works in your JSFiddle example, what behavior you expect?

Comment: @Farside The JSFiddle is displaying exactly the behaviour I described: the problem is not the toggling, it is the highlighting of the button. Start with both columns hidden. Click the button "First" then "Second". The button "First" will only get highlighting round it when you click on "Second", which is confusing at best.

Answer (score 0):

The jsFiddle works. I don't see any issues.

```
$(button).toggleClass("highlight", column.visible());
```

When you first click, then the column.visible() returns false, the highlight class is removed. When you secondly click the button, the column.visible()==true - the highlight class is added.

Though, I'd not recommend to use the *-webkit-focus-ring-color* outline, as it's **not supported** by most of the browsers, except webkit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about -webkit, it doesn't appear at all in the Edge browser. (It does in Chrome, my default.)
I'm definitely observing the behaviour I describe in Chrome, that the highlighting only appears when I click away. I will change the CSS to a different highlight, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Changing from outline: {-webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;} to {outline: 2px solid rgb(94, 158, 214);} seems to have fixed the problem.
It would still be interesting to know _why_ that happens, but I guess not crucial.

Comment: @Ollyver, if my answer somehow helped you, you may upvote. About your problem - I don't really understand. There's no obvious problem - the code works, and I explained above how it works. If you expect different behavior, please, elaborate what's wrong there.